# Is there a way to call a method every time revisit the screen in bottom nav bar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to call a method every time I revisit that tab in the bottom NAV Bar. I use Persistent Bottom Navigation Bar package.

Currently, I call that method in the initState and it only gets called once when the page first loads up. But I want it to be called every time I change to this tab from another tab.

Is there a way to do this?

[Link to the project](https://github.com/kahhui312/my_flutter_nav)

[image: Home Screen - Method that need to be called]

Comment: When you say persistent bottom nav var, is it this package?  https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar

Comment: Yes, it is. @JaredAnderton

Comment: Would you be willing/able to share more of your implementation? The example in their tutorial is incomplete (missing classes, lots of syntax errors), so it's not quick to create a replicate (and if possible, code - not a screen shot)

Comment: Sure, here is the link. https://github.com/kahhui312/my_flutter_nav @JaredAnderton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it's not my best work, but I think it accomplishes the goal. It does leverage another package, [visibility_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector)

Install:

```
dependencies:
  visibility_detector: ^0.2.2
```

Import the package:

```
import 'package:visibility_detector/visibility_detector.dart';
```

Listen for changes in visibility:

```
// Stateless
class ExploreScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExploreScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static String id = 'exploreScreen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return VisibilityDetector(
      key: Key(ExploreScreen.id),
      onVisibilityChanged: (VisibilityInfo info) {
        bool isVisible = info.visibleFraction != 0;
        callThisMethod(isVisible);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Explore Screen'),
        ),
        body: ... 
      ),
    );
  }
  void callThisMethod(bool isVisible){
    debugPrint('ExploreScreen.callThisMethod: isVisible: ${isVisible}');
  }
}

// Stateful
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // callThisMethod(); // Note I commented this out, for _my_ test. You might decide you want it
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return VisibilityDetector(
      key: Key(HomeScreen.id),
      onVisibilityChanged: (VisibilityInfo info) {
        bool isVisible = info.visibleFraction != 0;
        callThisMethod(isVisible);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Home Screen'),
        ),
        body: ... ,
      ),
    );
  }
  void callThisMethod(bool isVisible){
    debugPrint('_HomeScreenState.callThisMethod: isVisible: ${isVisible}');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

override `didChangeDependencies` and add your function call in it

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    callThisMethod();
  }
```